# Emacs macro variables

Tags: dired, files, eval, apply

Does Emacs have 'macro variables'?

Midnight Commander allows the use of macro substitution expressions like %f %D %t which can be use when running commands. eg %f is the name of the current file in a directory, %t refers to currently tagged files.

I'm sure Emacs has such a feature, but haven't figure it out yet...

Suppose I mark a number files and want to perform some command on all them, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please split your question in two. The question of the last paragraph seems separate from what comes before it.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your question in two. If you do, I'll move this answer to your post for your second question, *"Suppose I mark a number files and want to perform some command on all them, how would I go about doing that?"*

If you use [**Dired+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([**`dired+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)) then you have these commands:

- **`diredp-do-aggregate-apply-to-marked`**

  Aggregate results of applying a function to the marked files and dirs.
  This command prompts you for the aggregate function, `AGGREGATE-FUN`.  Then it calls `diredp-do-apply-to-marked`, which prompts you for a
  function to apply to the name of each marked file or dir.
- **`diredp-do-aggregate-eval-in-marked`**

  Aggregate results of evaluating a sexp in the marked files and dirs.
  This command prompts you for the aggregate function, `AGGREGATE-FUN`.
  Then it calls `diredp-do-eval-in-marked`, which prompts you for a Lisp
  sexp to evaluate in each marked file or dir.
- **`diredp-do-apply/eval-marked`**

  Apply a function to the marked files, or evaluate a sexp in them.
  Return a list of the results. You are prompted for the function or sexp.
- **`diredp-do-apply/eval-marked-recursive`**

  Apply a function to marked files, or evaluate a sexp in them.
  Like `diredp-do-apply/eval-marked` but act recursively on subdirs, and do no
  result-logging, error-logging or echoing.
  The files acted on are those that are marked in the current Dired
  buffer, or all files in the directory if none are marked.  Marked
  subdirectories are handled recursively in the same way.
- **`diredp-do-apply-to-marked`**

  Apply `FUNCTION` to the absolute name of each marked file.
  Return a list of the results.
  You are prompted for `FUNCTION`.
- **`diredp-do-apply-to-marked-recursive`**

  Apply `FUNCTION` to names of marked files, including in marked subdirs.
  The absolute file name is passed to `FUNCTION`.
  Like `diredp-do-apply-to-marked` but act recursively on subdirs, and
  do no result-logging, error-logging, or echoing.
  The files included are those that are marked in the current Dired
  buffer, or all files in the directory if none are marked.  Marked
  subdirectories are handled recursively in the same way.
- **`diredp-do-eval-in-marked`**

  Evaluate an Emacs-Lisp `SEXP` in each marked file.
  Visit each marked file at its beginning, then evaluate `SEXP`.
  Return a list of the results.
  You are prompted for the `SEXP`.
- **`diredp-do-eval-in-marked-recursive`**

  Evaluate `SEXP` in each of the marked files, including in marked subdirs.
  Like `diredp-do-eval-in-marked` but act recursively on subdirs, and do
  no result-logging, error-logging, or echoing.
  The files included are those that are marked in the current Dired
  buffer, or all files in the directory if none are marked.  Marked
  subdirectories are handled recursively in the same way.